# Decorator and inheritance: what happens when the decorator is applied to parent class

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, metaclass

Need some help to understand a decorator behavior...

Here's some code:

```
import random

class MyDecorator(object):
    """ Logger decorator, adds a 'logger' attribute to the class """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print(random.randint(1, 100), *args, **kwargs)
      
      self.cls = args[0]

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # Do something, inject some attribute
      setattr(self.cls, 'x', 1234)
      
      # Return an instance of the class
      return self.cls(*args[1:], **kwargs)

@MyDecorator
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    print(f'A {self.x}')
  
@MyDecorator
class B:
  """ Parent class """
  def __init__(self):
    print(f'B {self.x}')


class B1(B):
  """ Child class """
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.logger.info('Class B1 __init__()')
    

# Here the decorator is applied directly to the class that is going to be instantiated
# Decorator's __init__() receives the class as arg[0], so I can store it and use it when __call__()'ed
a = A()

# Here the decorator is not applied to the class being instantiated, rather to its parent class
# It looks like the decorator's __init__() is being called twice:
# - first time it do recceives the class to which it is applied (in this case, B)
# - second time it receives 3 arguments: a string containing the name of the child class, a tuple containing an instance of the decorator class itself and then some dict containing internal Python controls (I think)
b1 = B1()
```

Output:

```
82 <class '__main__.A'>
47 <class '__main__.B'>
52 B1 (<__main__.MyDecorator object at 0x7fd4ea9b0860>,) {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'B1', '__doc__': ' Child class ', '__init__': <function B1.__init__ at 0x7fd4e9785a60>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7fd4eaa0f828: empty>}
A 1234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    b1 = B1()
  File "main.py", line 12, in __call__
    setattr(self.cls, 'x', 1234)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x'
```

So, my questions are:

1. What happens when I apply the decorator to the parent class, but not to its children? Looks like the decorator is being called for both parent/child, and is passing different set of parameters in each case
2. How would I solve my "class instantiation thorugh a decorator" in this scenario? (everything is working in cases like A, where the decorator is being applied directly to the class being instantiated)
3. Should I really be returning and instance of the class? What would happen if I needed to chain some decorators? what should my `__call__` method look like in this scenario

```
@MyDecorator1
@MyDecorator2
class A():
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The problem here is you've replaced the classes `A` and `B` with an instance of `MyDecorator`

Comment: Please ask only one question at once as per [ask]. On top of multiple questions, there are multiple things wrong with your code, which just get obscured by your code doing multiple unrelated things at once but incomplete.

Comment: Formally, aplying decorator is a call performed after evaluating a ``class`` or ``def`` statement, with the result of the decorator replacing the result of the statement. That is literally all that ``@`` does. All the shenanigans of instantiation, inheritance, call-to-instantiation-forwarding, parameter sets, class-as-decorator and such just complicate things. What is the single thing you are trying to do or test?

Comment: It seems that your `MyDecorator` instance is being used as the metaclass... not sure why.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's not used as a metaclass, but since ``B1(B)`` inherits from an *instance* of ``B`` (actually, ``MyDecorator``) that is similar – consider that inheriting from "the class ``int``" is similar to "inheriting from an instance of ``type``".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi not sure I follow you, can you elaborate a little? Why is the instance of `MyDecorator` getting called with `deco(name, bases, namespace)`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi my goal was to have a `@Logger` decorator that simply injects a `self.logger` in the class, so I'll be able to ` self.logger.info()` in whatever method it has. It looks like it's working in most cases, but not in the cases where the decorator is applied to the parent class.

Comment: @F.F.Knob really, don't use a class-based decorator then. Use a function-based one, e.g. `def Logger(cls): cls.logger = logger` then make sure to `return cls`. The problem is that when you do `@MyDecorator` it si instantiating an instance of `MyDecorator`, and that is what is being assigned to the names `A` and `B`, so when you do `class B1(B): ...` then `B` **is not the class `B`**, it is an instance of `MyDecorator`. Weird stuff happens when you inherit from something that isn't a class

Comment: So I'm not sure if my logic is completly wrong in my `__init__` and `__call__`, or if I should change it somehow, in order to be able to receive either the `class` or the `name, bases, namespace` @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned...

Comment: @F.F.Knob I think fundamentally a decorator to simply set a class attribute is overkill, but if you *were* going to do that, I'd use the function-based approach I outlined above...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank's for the advice. My preference for the 'Decorator as a class' was only that, I preference. I actually thought they would be interchangeble, a matter of taste... But I do admit I had some trouble to find examples of 'decorators as classes decorating classes'

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ah! I got confused, it is trying to use `MyDecorator` as the metaclass (not an instance) because it is trying to use `type(base)` as the metaclass!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your probably right about it being overkill, I'm definetly not experienced enough in Python to tell, I'm actually just learning about decorators, but instead of following another path I still want to give your approach a try

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are right that this is in fact fully equivalent to declaring ``MyDecorator`` as the ``metaclass``. My initial guess was just that ``MyDecorator.__call__`` was used in place of ``type.__call__``. It's the same mechanism as "inheriting from ``ABC``" using "the metaclass ``type(ABC)`` (aka ``ABCMeta``)" – in this case, ``type(B)`` is ``MyDecorator`` so it is used as the metaclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, when you do:

```
@MyDecorator
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    print(f'A {self.x}')
```

You can think of this as is syntactic sugar for

```
class B:
  def __init__(self):
    print(f'B {self.x}')

B = MyDecorator(B)
```

The problem is, though, that now `B` *is an instance of `MyDecorator`*, i.e., now `B` doesn't refer to a class. So, when you inherit from `B` in:

```
class B1(B):
    pass
```

Weird things happen. The relevant weird thing -- the one that causes the error ultimately -- is that [when deciding on the metaclass to use](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass):

> 3.3.3.3. Determining the appropriate metaclass
>
> - if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then `type()` is used;
> - if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of `type()`,   then it is used directly as the metaclass;
> - if an instance of `type()` is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, **then the most derived metaclass is used.**
>
> **The most derived metaclass is selected from the explicitly specified metaclass (if any) and the metaclasses (i.e. `type(cls)`) of all
> specified base classes. The most derived metaclass is one which is a
> subtype of all of these candidate metaclasses.**

i.e. the third bullet-point happens, in this case, `type(instance_of_my_decorator)` is used as the metaclass, i.e. `MyDecorator`. So ultimately, and through a different route, `B1` now also refers to (another) instance of `MyDecorator`, one which got the string `"B1"` passed as it's first argument to the constructor, hence in `MyDecorator.__init__`:

```
 self.cls = args[0]
```

Is assigning that string, so when you reach:

```
setattr(self.cls, 'x', 1234)
```

In `__call__`, it fails with the error above.

Since all you want to do is assign an attribute to the class, simplest solution is not to use a class-based approach, instead, use a function:

```
def MyDecorator(cls):
    setattr(self.cls, 'x', 1234)
    return cls # important
```

This, of course, seems a bit of overkill. You should probably just set the attribute as a class attribute like you normally would, as part of the class definition statement, but if you insist on using a decorator, the above approach *would* work. Of course, this won't get inherited.

Comment: Thank you for have taking the time! Really helped me a lot